# Web Form not working

Tags: php, forms, webforms, submission, feedback

I have used the webformmailer.php that godaddy gives before with no problem. Now on this new site for whatever reason it's not working. Could anyone look at this code and tell me what's wrong with it or what's missing from it.

Thanks in Advance

```
    <div id='form_wrap'>
        <form id="contact-form" formaction="webformmailer.php" method="POST" >

    <p id="formstatus"></p>
            <textarea id="inputtext"></textarea>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="username" placeholder=" Full Name" />
            <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="username" placeholder=" Email "  />
            <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Submit" />

        </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: It's `action`, not `formaction`

Comment: and you have duplicate element id's, that is bad

Comment: ...not to mention GoDaddy.

Comment: Oops didn't see that. Thanks guys. Fred, who would you suggest as a hosting service?

Comment: @GaryNorris I'm in Canada, however you can use anyone. The one I use is a lot less complicated then GoDaddy and offers many options for FREE, compared to GoDaddy. Am not sure if `plugging` a hosting service is `up to par` on SO.

Comment: @GaryNorris As `andrewsi` stated earlier (deleted comment), you also had a doubled `form` statement. Try out my answer below, see if it works. If not, try to post your form handler code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, give this a whirl. (Should work, as I don't have your `webformmailer.php` code).

You also left the VALUE's empty. I popped 'em in there for ya.

```
<div id='form_wrap'>
    <form id="contact-form" action="webformmailer.php" method="POST" >

<p id="formstatus"></p>
        <textarea id="inputtext"></textarea>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="username" id="username" placeholder="Full Name" />
        <input type="text" name="email" value="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
</div>
```

---

This is assuming your form handler contains something to the affect of:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Comment: Do you have to have value="something" or could I just leave them out completely?

Comment: @GaryNorris Hm, I doubt that. Try it with and without the values. Hard to say without seeing your form handler code. Usually, form values match IDs; that's how I do it. It avoids confusion, for `me` anyway.

Comment: @GaryNorris Your form handler should have something similar to the affect of `$username = $_POST['username'];` etc. `$username` matching your `value="username"` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified:

```
formaction="webformmailer.php"
```

when it should be

```
action="webformmailer.php"
```